# Windows image backup without USB drive?

Tags: windows-10, system-recovery

Recently I created a system image of my PC because I needed to replace the HDD. So I did the replacement. I booted back up into the windows installation CD, and selected to restore my system from an image. Now gave me the error message that I was running ON the drive that I needed to format to restore the image. I did some testing, and even unplugging every drive except the install CD, it still gave me this message. After going crazy trying to figure this out, finally came across some things on google saying the message itself is meaningless and the error is because I am using a install CD and not a recovery disk.. OK well that made no sense to me but I accepted the fact I wouldn't be re imaging my PC and just went ahead and completely re installed windows. After getting everything setup, I went to make a recovery disk to be sure this wouldn't happen again.. Now when I go to make a recovery disk, it will ONLY ACCEPT USB drives. I do not want to store it on a usb drive. I want to store it on my backup HDD with the image.

1. Is it not possible to create a recovery disk on HDD instead of USB?
2. Why does microsoft make their products more terrible as time goes on? Why give fake error messages and disable functionality leaving users up the creek? Are they trying to push us to some better backup solution I'm not aware of?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Probably is "safe hardware" enabled on your UEFI, my suggestion is to disable that feature from UEFI. Another option is to do a device image (clonzilla is good for that) so you'll restore the clonzilla image on new HD. This also clone the HDD id, so uefy won't complain

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use an external drive for recovery (I do this all the time!) then there is a working alternative.

My suggestion is you consider using third-party backup solution.

I personally prefer to use third-party backup solutions as they tend to be both more flexible and more reliable than any built-in solutions.